# Enhanced Ecommerce only records setAction

Tags: google-analytics

I'm currently implementing Google Analytics enhanced ecommerce. When I buy something in my dev env I check my dev analytics Shopping Behavior and I only see values in All Sessions and Sessions with Transactions, but nothing in between. My code is below. Before or after each ga('ec') & ga('send') pair I sometimes fire an event for normal analytics. Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
// All values are angular expressions that I've
// double triple checked to make sure they give good values
ga('ec:addImpression', 'detail',{
    'id': $location.search().tripToken,
    'name': $scope.holds[a].value,
    'price': $scope.holds[a].price,
    'category' : tileDisable
});
ga('send','pageview')
// Next GA fire a bit later
ga('ec:addProduct', 'checkout', {
    'id': $location.search().tripToken,
    'name': optionType,
    'price': $scope.getOptionPrice(optionType),
    'quantity': parseInt($scope.baseInfo.total_travelers)
});
ga('send','pageview');
// A bit later
ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
    'id': $scope.userData.option_type,
    'affiliation': $scope.userData.token,
    'revenue': $scope.userData.option_price * $scope.baseInfo.total_travelers
});
ga('send','pageview');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For common impressions you have to remove the 'detail'

```
    ga('ec:addImpression' *** REMOVE ,'detail'***,{
    'id': $location.search().tripToken,
    'name': $scope.holds[a].value,
    'price': $scope.holds[a].price,
    'category' : tileDisable
    });
```

Then when a product is clicked you need to add

```
    ga('ec:addProduct', {
    'id': 'P12345',
    'name': 'Android Warhol T-Shirt',
    'category': 'Apparel',
    'brand': 'Google',
    'variant': 'black',
    'position': 1
    });

    ga('ec:setAction', 'click', {list: 'Search Results'});
    //Remember to add a (non interaction if you wish) event here in order to send the data to GA
    ga('send','event','whatever-value');
```

The last step would be adding the clic (add to cart) for the detail page:

```
    ga('ec:addProduct', {
    'id': product.id,
    'name': product.name,
    'category': product.category,
    'brand': product.brand,
    'variant': product.variant,
    'price': product.price,
    'quantity': product.qty
    });
    ga('ec:setAction', 'add');
    // Send data using an event again (depends on user interaction)
    ga('send', 'event', 'UX', 'click', 'add to cart');
```

In case you want to see a live example please visit official Google's demo:
http://enhancedecommerce.appspot.com/